# Angle bewteen two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, angle

I have encountered such problem that ask us to calculate the angle between two vectors:

> $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ has a length of $5$,$12$,$15$ respectively. Their sum gives a $\vec{0}$. **What is the angle between  $\vec{u}$ and $ \vec{v}$ ?**

My first thought is to use cosine law, which will be as following:

- $||\vec{w}||^2 = ||\vec{u}||^2+||\vec{v}||^2 - 2||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||\cos(\theta)$
- $\theta = \frac{||\vec{w}||^2 - ||\vec{u}||^2-||\vec{v}||^2}{- 2||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||} $
- $\theta = \arccos(\frac{-7}{15}) $

**However, the answer that the books give is $\arccos(\frac{7}{15})$**.

Also, this is the procedure provided by the book, which I found very confusing and I couldn't understand **(For exemple: Why did they come up with first two setps? What do they even mean?)**

[image]

And in the procedure provided, I found the book eventually use almost the same formula but with $2||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||\cos(\theta)$ **instead of** $- 2||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||\cos(\theta)$

So I truly don't know where is my mistake, and why the book and I just have a difference of sign?

Really need help on this one! Thank you!

Comment: Why would it be outside the triangle? This is where I can't understand (Since the two answers add up to 180, means one is inside and the other is outside. However, I don't know if I should be looking for the inside one or the outside one? And why?)

Comment: Angle between two vectors is where the tails meet. In the triangle, the tails do not meet.

Comment: Thank you! But do you understand what the book is trying to do here? By setting up such long formula for this question

Comment: It is showing the vector derivative of the law of cosines.

Comment: Okay. So for the first step for the response, how would you obtain such a formula just by knowing that the sum of the three vectors gives $\vec{0}$ ?

Comment: Every vector is orthogonal to the zero vector and thus produces a scalar product of $0$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much! Now I fully understand!

Comment: Off topic: Should someone write answer now as you have understood it ?

Comment: You mention that you get $\arccos(-7/15)$, but note that this is equal to the textbook answer as well (as $\arccos$ is an even function).

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris $\cos$ is an even function, $\arccos$ certainly not. $\arccos(7/15)\neq \arccos(-7/15).$

Comment: @Aretino No. $\arccos(x)=\pi-\arccos(-x)$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier You are right: you got that result because your  is the supplementary of the angle between  and  (see my answer).

Comment: @ReinhardMeier yup, you're totally right—just had a brain lapse for a second!

Answer (score 1):

Here's why you get the supplementary angle.

[image]